# How to trigger useEffect when a subcomponent renders?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I know we can trigger the `useEffect` hook either:

1. Every time the component renders.
2. When the component mounts and/or unmounts.
3. When one of the defined dependencies changes.

But is it possible to trigger it when a subcomponent renders?

Answer (score 0):

you can pass a function as prop to the child component and use a useEffect inside the child so that every time it renders again you can run the prop function

Comment: Thank you for your input. However, I am looking for a way to do it while keeping the useEffect call in the parent component.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do is to pass a callback to child compon3ent which would be invoked with each child component render. Now this callback would be updating one of the prop of parent component with your hook. Your hook can specify this prop as its dependency which means every time it changes, your hook be triggered. This would ensure you have your hook inside parent component only but the problem is hook would trigger parent component re-render and you are stuck in a loop. From what I can understand, you don't need a hook but something that keeps an eye on every render of child component and does something. A simple callback should be enough in this case